# Cannot get inner content error

Tags: vb.net, iis

I'm in the process of migrating a website from one of my clients staging servers to a hosted server for one of their clients.

Everything else is working fine except the media gallery section of the website. When trying to open a gallery page I'm getting the error:

**Cannot get inner content of ulGallerySlides because the contents are not literal.**

I'm more of a techie than a programmer so I'm a bit stumped as to what is causing this and how to fix it. It works perfectly on the staging server.

The staging server is an IIS 7 server which I have full control over and the new server is hosted at an ISP on IIS 8 and I have very little control of it (just through WebSitePanel)

The code behind it is:

```
    Public Sub BuildGalleryView()
    Dim objDA As New clsDataAccess
    Dim dtResults As New DataTable
    Dim iCounter As Integer = 0

    Dim intGalleryID As Integer = CInt(Request.QueryString("g"))


    Dim strGalleryTitle As String = ""
    Dim strGalleryDescription As String = "Test Gallery Description"
    Dim strMediaTitle As String = "Test Media Title"
    Dim strMediaDescription As String = "Test Media Description"
    Dim strMediaURL As String = "./assets/images/placeholder.jpg"

    dtResults = objDA.ODSGetGalleryMedia(intGalleryID).Tables(0)

    'Set the gallery info first
    strGalleryTitle = dtResults(0)("Gallery_Title").ToString
    strGalleryDescription = dtResults(0)("Gallery_Description").ToString

    lblGalleryTitle.InnerText = strGalleryTitle.ToString
    lblGalleryDescription.InnerText = strGalleryDescription.ToString
    lblGalleryMainTitle.InnerText = strGalleryTitle.ToString

    If Not dtResults Is Nothing Then

        'Loop through all the images and build the slider"
        For i As Integer = 1 To dtResults.Rows.Count

            strMediaTitle = dtResults(iCounter)("Media_Title").ToString
            strMediaDescription = dtResults(iCounter)("Media_Description").ToString
            strMediaURL = "./assets/" & dtResults(iCounter)("Media_URL").ToString

            ulGallerySlides.InnerHtml = ulGallerySlides.InnerHtml & _
                "<li>" & _
                    "<img src='" & strMediaURL & "' align='Slider'/>" & _
                    "<div class='flex-caption'>" & _
                        "<h2>" & strMediaTitle & "</h2>" & _
                        "<p>" & strMediaDescription & "</p>" & _
                    "</div>" & _
                "</li>"
            iCounter = iCounter + 1
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

What do I need to change to fix this?